# Crear consulta con whereNotIn en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo dos tablas `junta` , `voto` y quiero obtener las juntas que no tengan votos registrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he intentado de las siguientes formas y ninguna muestra el resultado esperado.

```
//TODO::forma 1
    $juntasVotos = DB::table('voto')->where('vot_estado', '=', 1)->get();
    foreach ($juntasVotos as $jv) {
        $data[] = $jv->junta_idjunta;
    }
    $data2 = array_unique($data);
    $junta1 = DB::table('junta')->whereNotIn('idjunta', $data2)->get();

    //TODO::forma 2
    $junta2 = DB::table('junta')->where('jun_estado', '=', 1)
        ->whereNotIn('idjunta', function ($query) {
            $query->select('junta_idjunta')
                ->from('voto');
        })->get();

    //TODO::forma 3
    $junta3 = DB::table('junta')
        ->select('idjunta')
        ->whereNotIn('idjunta', DB::table('voto')->pluck('junta_idjunta'))
        ->get();

    dd($junta3);
```

Comment: me causa duda, mencionas *todos los registros que se encuentren* pero tratas de usar el método `whereNotIn()` que de hecho hace lo contrario

Comment: es decir tratas de obtener todas las juntas que tienen votos emitidos?

Comment: adelante y te la califico trata de agregarle una explicación detallada, te hubiera ayudado pero no me quedaba claro tu enunciado

Comment: hola amigo, lo que necesito es obtener las juntas que no tienen votos registrados, y ya resolví el problema. voy a enviar como respuesta en caso de que alguien lo necesite.

Comment: @shadow listo gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

La solución a mi problema fue la siguiente, en primer lugar la variable `data[]` tiene registros con el mismo `junta_idjunta`, por lo cual primero se debe limpiar los registros duplicados con la siguiente función `array_unique` y reindexarlos con la función `array_values`.

```
    $juntasVotos = DB::table('voto')->where('vot_estado', '=', 1)->get();
    $listas = lista::where('lis_estado', '=', 1)->get();

        foreach ($juntasVotos as $jv) {
            $data[] = $jv->junta_idjunta;
        }

        $data2 = array_values(array_unique($data));
        $junta1 = DB::table('junta')->whereNotIn('idjunta', $data2)->get();
```